# SQL integrated security using computer name instead of user name

Tags: .net, sql, authentication, connection-string

I am trying to an SQL Express instance on the same network, authenticating with my domain user. It works just fine with Windows Authentication in SSMS. I verified that I can use the MyDB database, including editing tables.

However, when I try the following connection string:

`Server=ipaddress\SQLExpress; Database=MyDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;`

I get back an error:

`Cannot open database "MyDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'ROMANIA\MONSTER2$'`

The problem is that MONSTER2 is the name of my computer, not my username. (ROMANIA is the domain.) What am I doing wrong?

[Edit] I forgot something that might be relevant: I am trying to open the connection from a webservice running on my computer.

Comment: You need to configure your webservice to run as a named using (rather than local machine, as it appears to be)

Comment: What an annoying quirk. Thanks for posting this question. Helped me out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your web service is running under the `NT AUTHORITY\Network Service` security context. This will cause the process to **use the host's machine account when accessing network resources** in the domain.

You'll have to configure the web service to run with your domain identity.

If you're hosting your web service in IIS, you can do this through [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Here's an example:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <identity
            impersonate="true"
            userName="ROMANIA\username" 
            password="********" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Once again, I have the problem of choosing which answer to mark as accepted. I'll pick this one, sorry Raj. I up-voted both answers though.

Answer (score 15):

That is because your web server is not set up to use the identity of the person using the service, but rather the identity of the computer it is running on.

Check if your web.config for the web service contains: `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

Comment: Duh! You are correct. For the record, I had to go to IIS and change the application pool (in advanced settings) to use my identity instead of the default ApplicationPoolIdentity. I'll accept the answer in 9 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do both in my situation:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and for a similar reason. (blush).

Even though I correctly set up my application pool to use the service account credentials instead of the LocalService/NetworkService etc, for some reason the Application itself *was not using that application pool*. It was set to DefaultAppPool. Very easy to miss, if one continues to assume that IIS was set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the applications hosted on IIS are running under the correct application pool rather than the DefaultAppPool.