# Its trying to connect as DOMAIN/COMPUTERNAME instead of DOMAIN/USERNAME

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Unable to connect with sql server with servlet.

its on tomcat 7 which says

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:sqlserver://;integratedSecurity=true");

Getting error: 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\SUMIT-PC$'.

SUMIT-PC is my computer's name.
it should be 'MYDOMAIN\SUMIT SINGH'

Comment: Is your service running as "Local Machine" account? If so, let it run as a dedicated user. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6761596/21567) for a related question.

Answer (score 4):

This means that your tomcat is running under LocalSystem account in domain-based network. If you want to make tomcat to use your login propagation - you should to tune up it to impersonate logged on user and your tomcat and sql server(or workstation for windows 2003 domains) should be **trusted for delegation** on domain level, and user `MYDOMAIN\SUMIT SINGH` should be also not denied for delegation on domain level.

**or**

implement your own impersonation inside the server process - this requires you to know user's password

Comment: But I can access sql server only the base of windows authentication or SQL auth (Mixed). I cant access it with username and password

Comment: Or it would be great if u describe me steps to do that.

Comment: If you'll not tune delegation - you should do impersonation inside server process - see here for details: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User

Comment: I solved it using impersonation. Works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

Today I got the same issue. In my machine, it was Tomcat 8.5 and I have installed tomcat as a windows service. (installed using `apache-tomcat-8.5.40.exe`)

Press the `Win + R` keys on your keyboard, to open the `Run` window. Then, type `services.msc` and hit `Enter` or press `OK`.

[image]

Right click on Tomcat service and select `Properties`. In that dialog box go to `Log On` tab and select `This Account` under `Log on as` option. Fill your username, password as well. Then click `OK`.

Then restart the service!!!